# How to escape characters in regex of Androguard?

Tags: android, regex, static-analysis, androguard

I am using Androguard to do a static analysis of an apk file. I am using

```
a, d, dx = AnalyzeAPK("/app-debug.apk", decompiler="dad")
```

to decompile the apk. Then I am doing

```
d.get_regex_strings(".*PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.*").
```

I know that the string PackageManager.NameNotFoundException must be in there because it is my own application for which I have the source code. However, Androguard tells me that it could not find the string.

I also tried variations, such as

```
d.get_regex_strings(".*PackageManager\.NameNotFoundException.*")
```

or

```
d.get_regex_strings(".*PackageManager.*NameNotFoundException.*").
```

The problem seems to be the dot in the middle between PackageManager and NameNotFoundException. So, how do I escape characters in Androguard?

Comment: Double the backslash to escape the dot: `\\.`. However, `".*PackageManager.*NameNotFoundException.*"` should work. Then, it is not a regex problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Doubling the backslash did not work. So, it seems that Androguard does not support the usual regex functionality.

Comment: It seems it does acc. to documentation. BTW, did you try `a.get_vm().get_regex_strings(...)`? Not sure if it is the same, but I see something like this in [GitHub](https://github.com/androguard/androguard/blob/master/demos/androguard_ANALYSIS.py).

Comment: I tried `dx.get_vm().get_regex_strings(...)` and unfortunately it did not work. Same as for my original attempt, I am able to get the strings "PackageManger" and "NameNotFoundException" individually, but the dot seems to break the regex somehow.